# i want a method which can will wait for all the webelements in a page to load in java(Selenium webdiver)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
//I have used waits like 
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

or

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoad(100,TimeUnit.seconds);
```

or

```
driver.manage().timeouts().explicitlywait(10,TimeUnit.seconds);
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityof(element));
```

My concern is when running a large number of Scripts in Grid
    some pass some fail due to the wait issue
    So i want a user defined method that can handle such scenarios i.e. a method that shall wait for all elements of a page to load so that can be effectively used with methods that show errors like "Unable to locate element" or "unable to click a  element other elements will receive the click".*/*

Comment: Your question is not clear.   Why exactly are the "large number of scripts" failing "due to wait issue"?  `.pageLoad`  is the correct way to wait for the page to load - if you are getting some kind of race conditions, it's not from this function returning before the inline elements of the page load.

Comment: (OTOH, if the "elements" that are loading are due to AJAX requests running in JS or otherwise JS adding content - there is no way to do what you want except on a case-by-case basis)

Comment: I am thinking that if we can store all the webelements in a List and  then iterate through all along with a selenium wait(explicit / Implicit) against each element.But this will affect the total script execution timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You never should use timers for wait the load of your page, as you never know how fast is going to be render, then in this case I propose you 2 aproachs:

1. Use the method waitFor of Selenium where the driver will wait until the expetcted element is present, you can set the max time by default waiting, by default are 6 seconds. For this approach you need to know which element means the page is fully loaded

   ```
   waitFor(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("yourExpectedIdElement")));
   ```
2. If you need to check all your JS code is loaded, you also could add a line in your document.ready() JS where add a hidden element to the body, then is that attribute which you will wait in your tests.

   ```
   $document.ready(){
       //Add a hidden element to the body  
   }

   waitFor(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("createdElement")));
   ```